# Apache2 sends two HTTP headers with a mapped "nph-" CGI

Tags: apache, apache2, cgi, apache2.4

### Summary

I'm trying to map some file extensions to be executed by a nph (Non Parsed Header) CGI executable.

Let's say I want to access a URL `http://server/file.ext` and map the "ext" file extension to "trigger" the execution of my nph CGI (/var/www/cgi-bin/nph-test.sh).

### Apache configuration

To do that I'm using mod_actions and mod_cgid, this is my relevant configuration information:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /var/www/cgi-bin

        Action cgi-wrapper /cgi-bin/nph-test.sh

        AddHandler cgi-wrapper .ext
</VirtualHost>
```

### NPH CGI script

This is my nph-test.sh shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "HTTP/1.0 200 OK"
echo "Server: Shell/1.0"
echo "Status: 200 \"OK\""
echo "Connection: close"
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><body><pre>"
echo "QUERY_STRING = "${QUERY_STRING}
echo "PATH_TRANSLATED = "${PATH_TRANSLATED}
echo "</pre></body></html>"
```

### Problem

When I access nph-test.sh with this URL `http://localhost/cgi-bin/nph-test.sh?Hello` I get:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: Shell/1.0
Status: 200 "OK"
Connection: close
Content-type: text/html

<html><body><pre>
QUERY_STRING = Hello
PATH_TRANSLATED =
</pre></body></html>
```

The problem appears when using the file mapping like in this URL `http://localhost/file.ext` I get a **double** http header (it's treating the nph cgi script like a **non** nph cgi script):

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: Shell/1.0
Status: 200 "OK"
Connection: close
Content-type: text/html

<html><body><pre>
QUERY_STRING =
PATH_TRANSLATED = /var/www/htdocs/file.ext
</pre></body></html>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
Date: Tue, 18 Mar 2014 14:32:29 GMT^M
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)^M
Content-Length: 0^M
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100^M
Connection: Keep-Alive^M
Content-Type: text/x-sh^M
^M
```

### My findings

After searching for some hours I only found this [2003 apache bug report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22898). Which also suggests a patch that in theory has not being applied.

But searching the current [mod_cgid source code](http://people.apache.org/~igalic/checks/httpd/2012-09-14-2/report-hrDYB3.html) I can see that the code has been changed to be able to capture the "nph-" cgi file prefix (strrchr):

```
1372 if ((argv0 = strrchr(r->filename, '/')) != NULL) {
1373    argv0++;
1374 }
1375 else {
1376    argv0 = r->filename;
1377 }
1378    
1379 nph = !(strncmp(argv0, "nph-", 4));
```

### Question

Is there a way with apache2 to map a file extension to a nph cgi? (without returning two http headers)

Are there other ways to do that or any workarounds?

### Apache and OS server information

I'm using the default apache2 server in Ubuntu 13.10:

```
# apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Dec  5 2013 18:32:22
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:23
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Compiled using: APR 1.4.8, APR-UTIL 1.5.2
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

### Update: Solution

The changed configuration to solve the problem using the mod_rewrite module:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /var/www/cgi-bin

        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*\.ext)$ /cgi-bin/nph-test.sh?$1 [PT]

        RewriteRule ^/?(.*\.ext)$ /cgi-bin/nph-test.sh?$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible (directly) on the 2.4.x source code.
As you correctly pointed out the bug is currently in [reopened status](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22898).

The proposed patch consists of two main modification:

1. Fix the nph- detection (and this part is currently in the source tree)
2. Getting rid of all remaining output filters (this part is *missing* in the source tree)

I'm not able to test, but I think it's possible to workaround this bug using mod_rewrite:
Looking in mod_rewrite documentation seems working just fine with [nph](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/advanced.html#autorefresh)

You can find a complete nph- + mod_rewrite example in [documentation page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/advanced.html#autorefresh)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I'll definitely try to use the mod_rewrite. It will take some time for me to test it as I've to setup again the environment... Then I'll mark your answer as the correct one